# Linking protobuf when used in static library

Tags: visual-c++, protocol-buffers

I am able to build small program that uses protobuf. Problem is when situation becomes a bit more complicated: I have simple static library, where I use protobuf. Then I have sample program that uses this library. Problem is that not all protobuf symbols are resolved. In VS solution I have my static library and sample program. Paths to both libraries are set and libraries are added to dependencies. Both libraries are seen (symbols from my library are resolved and part of protobuf symbols are also resolved) but some symbols from protobuf library remain unresolved. What do I have to set/change in my or protobuf VS solution to make it work?

Comment: Usually it helps to provide compiler's full error messages.

Comment: Full error messages contained unresolved symbols, but maybe I should put it anyway. But problem solved itself. I guess there was a bug with project or project settings. I restarted VS, created new solution and it works now.